# where to put limit and offset?

Tags: php, codeigniter

this code is written by Codeigniter and it is in the models folder
I need to add

```
$this->db->limit($limit,$offset);
```

to following code. Where do I put it? The model code is here

```
$this->db->where('comments.product_id', $product_id);
        $this->db->select('comments.comment,comments.ratings,comments.comment_users_id,comment_users.name');
        $this->db->from('comments');
        $this->db->join('comment_users', 'comment_users.id = comments.comment_users_id');
        $this->db->join('product', 'product.product_id=comments.product_id');
        $this->db->order_by('comments.id', 'DESC');     
        return $this->db->get()->result();
```

Comment: put it before the last line. however i'm not sure the order matters except for readability. codeigniter constructs the query from the different sections specified.

Comment: i think order is doesn't matter in codeingniter

Comment: Insert the line between order_by and return.

Answer (score 0):

Order is doesn't matter just do like this

```
$this->db->where('comments.product_id', $product_id);
    $this->db->select('comments.comment,comments.ratings,comments.comment_users_id,comment_users.name');
    $this->db->from('comments');
    $this->db->join('comment_users', 'comment_users.id = comments.comment_users_id');
    $this->db->join('product', 'product.product_id=comments.product_id');
    $this->db->order_by('comments.id', 'DESC');   
    $this->db->limit($limit,$offset);  //here added 
    return $this->db->get()->result();
```